# Type 'Selection<HTMLElement>' is not assignable to type 'Selection<SVGElement>'

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js, svg, types

This is a very confusing issue. In my class I've defined three properties; `target` and `leftSidebar` of type `d3.Selection<HTMLElement>`, and `svg` of type `d3.Selection<SVGElement>`.

In the code below, `options.element` just refers to a raw div (so it's of type `HTMLElement`).

This code works fine:

```
    this.target = d3.select(options.element);
    this.leftSidebar = this.target.append("section")
        .attr("id", "leftSidebar");
    this.svg = d3.select(options.element).append("section")
        .attr("id", "svg-container")
        .append("svg");
```

however when I change the bottom statement so the code is as following:

```
    this.target = d3.select(options.element);
    this.leftSidebar = this.target.append("section")
        .attr("id", "leftSidebar");
    this.svg = this.target.append("section")
        .attr("id", "svg-container")
        .append("svg");
```

then I get the error shown in the title.

This doesn't make sense to me at all, because all I've done is change `d3.select(options.element)` to `this.target`, but `this.target` is equal to `d3.select(options.element)`!

Why is this happening?

(I'm using d3 3.5.17 with ES5 as my TypeScript target)

Comment: Can you cast it to `Selection<SVGElement>`? `this.svg = <Selection<SVGElement>> ...`

Comment: @Arg0n no, then I get `Type 'Selection<HTMLElement>' cannot be converted to type 'Selection<SVGElement>'` (followed by a list of incompatibilities between them).

Comment: And what about cast to `<any>`? If it returns what you think it should, then there should be no problem tricking/forcing it.

Comment: What is the declared type of `this.target` in your class (i.e. `target:*insertTypeHere*`?

Comment: @Arg0n this does work, however I'm still intrigued as to why this is happening. Plus, casting to any seems like a hacky solution, no?

Comment: @HuguesStefanski `d3.Selection<HTMLElement>`

Comment: Then that is you problem. `d3.select(option.element)` most likely returns a `d3.Selection<any>` or `d3.Selection<*multpleChoices>`, compatible with SVGElement, while using target considers it HTMLElement, therefore considering all `append` of the same type. Maybe you can call `append<SVGElement>` to specify the return type?